# cant find size of text in setText method in textview

Tags: android, textview

I have a custom class that extends TextView that replaces the last character with a custom bitmap emoji.  For some reason the emoji is always much smaller than the text. here is the overridden method

```
@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    super.setText("H", type);
    SpannableString span = new SpannableString(text);
    Bitmap emoji = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.emoji);
    int size = (int) (-this.getPaint().ascent());
    Bitmap scaledEmoji = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(emoji, size, size, true);
        emoji.recycle();
    ImageSpan ispan = new ImageSpan(c, scaledEmoji, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
        span.setSpan(ispan, text.length()-1, text.length(), 0);
    }
    super.setText(span, type);
}
```

Edit: ok so the problem is the setText method is being called before the constructor.  I don't get the issue if I set the text pragmatically rather than in the xml.  But I would like to know if there is a fix for that and how it's even possible to call a method on an object before instantiating it.

Comment: when u will make the instance of this text view there u can set the size,.

Comment: THe initial super.setText to "H" in your call is useless at best and harmful at worst.  Get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ImageSpan ispan = new ImageSpan(c, scaledEmoji,ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
  spannable.setSpan(ispan, getText().length()-1,
    getText().length() + emoji.length(),
    Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```